# Trying to decrypt a file that has a string password, gnupg.py requires password to be a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, gnupg

I have an application that uses gnupg.py to decrypt a file stream in python 2. I can create a GPG object, open my file as a stream, and decrypt it using GPG methods. I migrated my application to python 3. I tried to run it again, with out changing the creation of the GPG object or the GPG methods used for the decryption of the file.

- The gnupg.py version I am using is 0.4.6. The author is Vinay Sajip. The date and time of the release is 17-Apr-2020 09:35:35.
- The version of Python I am using to test this is 3.6.6.
- Linux 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64
- Distro: "CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"

```
import os
from myPropLib.pgp import StreamingGPG

def main():

    print("Starting\n")

    inputFilePath = “/tmp/encryp_input_file.dat.gpg”

    pgp_password = ‘XXXXXXXXXX’  # passphrase is a string

    pgp = StreamingGPG()

    with pgp.decrypt_file_stream(inputFilePath, passphrase=pgp_password) as data_file:

        print("before the read\n")
        result = data_file.read()

    print("result: ", result,"\n")

    print("Completed\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- pgp_password is the password gnupg needs to decrypt the file.
- Object pgp is a StreamingGPG object, which is a wrapper for gnupg’s GPG object initialized with no parameters set (all default values).
- Method pgp.decrypt_file_stream(file, passphrase) is used to create and execute a gpg command that can decrypt a file. It uses two GPG methods:

_open_subprocess(args, passphrase): create a gpg command using subprocess.Popen:

```
  result = Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, startupinfo=si)
```

where cmd has a list of elements to create a gpg command like this:

```
  gpg --status-fd 2 --no-tty --no-verbose --fixed-list-mode --batch --with-colons --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt /tmp/encryp_input_file.dat.gpg
```

This command does decrypt the file if executed manually from the prompt and using the correct string passphrase.

_write_passphrase(p.stdin, passphrase, self.encoding): writes the passphrase to stdin.

However, this version gets stuck at the read statement:

> result = data_file.read()

I think this is because in python 3 the standard-out object is an _io.BufferedReader, and reading is blocked. Using “http://eyalarubas.com/python-subproc-nonblock.html”, I set the O_NONBLOCK flag using package fcntl.

```
import os
from myPropLib.pgp import StreamingGPG
from fcntl import fcntl, F_GETFL, F_SETFL

def main():

    print("Starting\n")

    inputFilePath = “/tmp/encryp_input_file.dat.gpg”

    pgp_password = ‘XXXXXXXXXX’  # passphrase is a string

    pgp = StreamingGPG()

    with pgp.decrypt_file_stream(inputFilePath, passphrase=pgp_password) as data_file:

        # O_NONBLOCK flag is necessary to deal with the io.BufferedReader object.
        # Otherwise the process stops when trying to read the io.BufferedReader

        flags = fcntl(data_file, F_GETFL)
        fcntl(data_file, F_SETFL, flags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

        print("before the read\n")
        result = data_file.read()

    print("result: ", result,"\n")

    print("Completed\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This version does attempt to read from data_file, but it fails because of a bad password. The issue seems to be that in Python 3 the Popen command creates a standard-in that is an _io.BufferedWriter object, and it only accepts bytes-like objects to be written to it. Otherwise it returns the error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

For the case of this example, the pgp_password written to data_file’s standard-in would be a bytes like object (the newline is needed and is correct):

> b’XXXXXXXXXX\n’

But I believe that the this password is incorrect for the encrypted file and the gpg command trying to decrypt it. The correct password would be this string:

> ‘XXXXXXXXXX\n’

I have tested the resulting gpg command by using this string password and it decrypts the file correctly.

So if I am understanding this situation correctly, I think I am in a catch-22: in Python 3, the standard-in object (_io.BufferedWriter) for the gpg command created requires that the passphrase be a bytes-like object in order to be written to the standard-in; but that passphrase is incorrect for the file that I am trying to decrypt, which requires that the passphrase be string, so it cannot decrypt it.

I have also run this script using a Python 2 interpreter and I am able to decrypt the file.

**Is there a way for me to use the gnupg package in Python 3, where it can decrypt files that require a password that is a string, not a bytes-like object?**

Comment: Just encode it into bytes. GPG will require bytes because encryption operates on logic - and some characters in unicode take more than one byte. `my_password.encode()`. When it comes to cli, you write a string but it's being passed as bytes anyways. - stdin, stdout, and stderr are binary streams which pass binary information around - interpretation of those is purely on who reads them. That's why a lot of programs can get files piped into them or be redirected to file - i/o streams are computer thing (bytes), not human (unicode)